# How to connect quarkus Kakfa Consumer jar file with JMX Exporter properly?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus, javaagents, jmx-exporter

I am trying to attach the javaagent with my jar file in which I have implemeneted a simple Kafka Consumer in Quarkus. I plan on pushing the consumer-metrics to the specifed port, with the help of the following command

```
java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=9080:kafkaconsumer.yml -jar ./quarkus-run.jar
```

I get the following error,

`Error: Could not find or load main class io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint`

It asks for a main method but in Quarkus there is no main method. Is there a way around this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the JMX Exporter?

Quarkus uses [Micrometer](https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer) (recommended) or [SmallRye Metrics](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-metrics) to expose Prometheus data. You should wire internal JMX metrics through those endpoints instead, and Micrometer defaults to enabling JVM metrics.